# How do I setup VS Code for Angular Debugging?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup Visual Studio Code for debugging Angular.  If I just use the out-of-the-box version of launch.json and point it to the /js/app.js file, it returns:

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

So, I tried to use gulp-connect to start a server.  This starts the app just fine, but the debugger isn't attached and it never stops at breakpoints.

Can someone show me how to debug an angular web with VS Code?

PS.  Here is my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Launch Debug with gulp.js",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "js/app.js",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "args": [],
    "cwd": ".",
    "runtimeExecutable": null,
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy"
    ],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "externalConsole": false,
    "sourceMaps": false,
    "outDir": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Attach",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 5858
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why not just use developer tools in the browser?

Comment: if you want angular not defined to go away you need to import the angular.d.ts file.

Comment: I'd like to debug from the ide if possible.  The browser is just clunky (imho).  I'll try importing the ts file.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, with the help of the @code folks, I got it working. I'm now able to fully debug an Angular client from the IDE! Hopefully, this will help someone else...

First, you need to download the "Debugger for Chrome Extension." You do this by typing this:

```
F1
ext Install Extensions
debug (then select Debugger For Chrome)
```

Once that is installed, I used MSFT's instructions found here:

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome
```

I only can get the "attach" method working, so I use that with Chrome. Here is the final version of the launch.son file I use:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use this to get debug version of Chrome running:
            // /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "./www"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, don't forget to start Chrome in debug mode with this (for Mac):

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Comment: if you are using Visual Code to attach, how are you starting the application? are you following the steps `1>start server manually ( eg from console window)` `2>browse application in chrome ( eg localhost:4000\home)` `3>run VS debugger with attach option`